# Dojo versus extjs framework

Tags: javascript, web-services, extjs, dojo

I am looking at creating a webapp with a "rich" UI interface. I was looking at dojo and extjs and trying to evaluate what might be a better choice for my requirements. 
Just to give a brief idea of my requirement, this is the scenario:

I have several components stored in a data store. I wish to show them in the browser with the following UI.

Providing tree/table views of my components.

Displaying my components on a map (google)  to be able to view their geographic positions.

Ability to select multiple components in the map and setup connections (lines) between them so that they appear to be linked

PS:
I tried looking up some comparisons of extJs and dojo, but they seem to be from some years ago and are probably not as relevant anymore.

I am a newbie to the web UI frameworks and so ease of use of one over the other would also be a factor for me

thanks a lot

Comment: I'd suggest prototyping your app or usecase in both and then deciding which one you like better.

Comment: I don't think you are going to get an impartial answer to your question. Most of the SO info related to comparing the two is not too dated but won't help with decision very much.

Answer (score 1):

if you are new to the web UI frameworks, I recommend you use ExtJS, it has better documentation and easy to use, especially its UI design is much more better/modern than dojotoolkit, and it's more polished at industry level.

dojotoolkit is more for the advanced user (coder, geek), it has a lot of cool concepts/patterns, it's the first framework which has implemented AMD and has supported NodeJs. At technical level, it's the best. but until now, it still demands a lot of learning curve.

Honestly, I prefer dojo (at technique level) , but for a new comer, I suggest you use Extjs, You can probably achieve 90% of the work with ExtJs.